# Finder icon size slider broken, how to fix?

Tags: macos

The slider in the bottom-right corner of Finder windows doesn't change the icon size for me. This is of course with "Icon View" selected. What am I doing wrong? It worked before, up until Lion.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in **Thumbnail view**, press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>2</kbd> (to get the **List view**) and then switch back to **Thumbnail view** with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd>.
Normally, it should get your slider working!

Comment: Never use List view so I wouldn't have discovered your fix. Thank you!